# Docker - "Missing script: "dev"" - But it's there?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I'm using Docker Compose for a React/Express application.

Dockerfile for the server:

```
FROM node:latest 
WORKDIR /app/server 
COPY package.json /app/server
COPY package-lock.json /app/server 
RUN npm install 
COPY . /app/server
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

Dockerfile for the client:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app/client
COPY package.json /app/client
COPY package-lock.json /app/client
RUN npm install
COPY . /app/client
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

And my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3' 
services:
    server:
        build: ./server
        expose: 
            - "3001"
        ports:
            - "3001:3001"
        volumes:
            - ./server/src/:/app/server
        command: npm run dev
        tty: true

    client:
        build: ./client
        expose:
            - "3000"
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        volumes: 
            - ./client/src/:/app/client
        links:
            - server
        command: npm run start
        tty: true
```

After running "docker-compose up" the server crashes:

> npm ERR! Missing script: "dev"

However, I DO have a "dev" script inside my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
```

What is the problem here? The script is there. Is there something wrong with my Docker files? "npm run dev" works just fine without Docker.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `docker-compose.yml` file says

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./server/src/:/app/server
```

this hides everything the Dockerfile did in the `/app/server` directory and replaces it with the contents of that host directory.  Since the only things your Dockerfile does are in the `/app/server` directory, you're essentially not using your Docker image at all.

I'd generally recommend removing these `volumes:`, along with some other unnecessary options.  (You do not need to `expose:` ports in Compose pretty much ever; you do not need to repeat the `command:` from the image; `links:` are obsolete networking setup.)  You can reduce the file to just

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
    server:
        build: ./server
        ports:
            - "3001:3001"
    client:
        build: ./client
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
```

If you do include `volumes:`, you need to make sure that the layout of the mounted content exactly matches what's supposed to be in the container.  (Try running `docker-compose run server ls` with and without the `volumes:` line.)  Here you're building the image from the `./server` directory, but then mounting its `src` subdirectory over the whole application.  It may work better to mount it only on the `src` subdirectory inside the container too

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./server/src:/app/server/src
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, apparently, Docker can't find a package.json file that includes a `dev` script.

My first suggestion would be to ensure that package.json is in the root folder of the project, at the same folder level as the docker-compose.yml.

Comment: I have a package.json file inside my "server" folder and one inside my "client" folder. The one in the server folder has the "dev" script inside. But if docker can't find it - shouldn't "npm install" fail during "docker build"? Because it doesn't.

Comment: And so you have two `Dockerfile`s, one inside "client", and one inside "server"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. One Dockerfile for each folder.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a "/" at the end of all the "COPY" lines. So you would write " COPY package.json /app/server/" for that, and do it for all of the "COPY" lines. I'm not sure if Docker is THAT brittle, but it's something to try.

Comment: Nope, didn't work unfortunately :( But thanks for the effort!